# Spring MVC and AJAX error

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc

In JSP file I have field to enter student's group and then pass this data to entity class GroupStudent (without getter and setter methods)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GroupStudent")
@NamedQueries({ 
@NamedQuery(name = "GroupStudent.getAllGroups", // get all groups
            query = "select g from GroupStudent g"),
@NamedQuery(name = "GroupStudent.getGroupByName", // get group by name
            query = "select g from GroupStudent g where g.groupStudentNumber = :name")
})
public class GroupStudent implements Serializable {
public GroupStudent() {}

public GroupStudent(String groupStudentNumber) {
    this.groupStudentNumber = groupStudentNumber;
}
// table GroupStudent fields
private Long groupStudentId;
private String groupStudentNumber;
}
```

JSP

```
<label>Group</label>
<input id="groupStudentNumber"/>
<input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="addGroupAjax()" />
```

and ajax function to pass data to Spring Controller

```
function addGroupAjax() {
            var groupStudentNumber = $('#groupStudentNumber').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/IRSystem/addData.html",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{groupStudentNumber:" + groupStudentNumber + "}",
                success: function(response) {

                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert("Error" + e);
                }
            });
        }
```

but it do not pass data to controller. The field of the entity is empty.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addData.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Student addNewGroup(@ModelAttribute(value = "group") GroupStudent group) {

    System.out.println("Entered group: " + group.getGroupStudentNumber());

    return new Student();
}
```

and another thing that i can not pass entity Student to ajax too. I added to Spring jars

jackson-core-asl-1.7.1 and jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1 to be able to pass entity object to ajax. But it gave not result. When i try to pass data (to ajax) in Google Chrome I have a window with error Error[object Object].
I do not know why it happens. I would appreciate any information, thank you.

Comment: Show us what `GroupStudent` class looks like.

Comment: Change url in ajax function call to url: "addData.html" I mean remove /IRSystem/

Comment: I have added GroupStudent class.

Comment: jdev, if I delete that part i will get error 404.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is not properly set up to accept the post. If you are posting a JSON body, you need to use the `@RequestBody` annotation for your method parameter, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addData.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Student addNewGroup(@RequestBody GroupStudent group) {
    System.out.println("Entered group: " + group.getGroupStudentNumber());
    return new Student();
}
```

This way, your JSON will be directly mapped to your `GroupStudent` object.

Comment: You are right it was my mistake, i read about it but forgot to change. But still i have error Error[object Object] from browser when i try to pass data from ajax to controller or from controller to ajax (if I pass data to ajax without any @RequestBody parameter).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the consumes media type by adding consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE into your @RequestMapping.